# How can I get the MiKTeX console to open through new WinEdt?

Tags: winedt, miktex-update

I just installed MiKTeX using the basic-miktex-21.8-x64.exe installer.  After installing, it asked me to update. I did that successfully.  Then I installed WinEdt 10, Build: 20180507  (v. 10.3) - 64-bit.  It works, including that it installs necessary packages on the fly.  However, I cannot open the MiKTeX console through the console icon in WinEdt.

When I try, I immediately get an error in a popup window, saying

> Sorry, but something went wrong. Do you want to see the error details?

When I click yes, I get the MiKTeX error report, MiKTeX console:

> C:\jenkins\workspace\miktex\windows\build\source\Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\Session\texmfroot.cpp:238:
> internal error

I have tried restarting the computer. That made no difference.  I can open the MiKTeX console from the start menu.  But what can I do to get the console icon in WinEdt to open the console?

Is it just a setting I need to change in WinEDt options?  Or something like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinstalled MiKTeX, this time as admin.  Now the MiKTeX console opens through MiKTeX console icon in WinEdt.